# Find shortest path in the matrix for multiple objects

Tags: java, concurrency

I have the implementation of A* search algorithm that allows to find the shortest path from start to goal.

The implementation looks like this

```
public class AStarShortestPathContext {

    private Vertex[][] matrix;
    private int rows, columns;
    private int cost;
    private PriorityQueue<Vertex> openList;
    private Set<Vertex> closedSet;

    public AStarShortestPathContext(int rows, int columns, int cost) {
        this.rows = rows;
        this.columns = columns;
        this.cost = cost;

        openList = new PriorityQueue<>(Comparator.comparingInt(Vertex::getF));
        closedSet = new HashSet<>();
    }

    public List<Vertex> find(Vertex startVertex, Vertex goalVertex, boolean[][] blocked) {
        refreshContext();

        Vertex start = new Vertex(startVertex);
        Vertex goal = new Vertex(goalVertex);

        ComputationUtils.updateEuristic(matrix, goal);

        openList.add(start);
        while (!openList.isEmpty()) {
            Vertex current = openList.poll();
            closedSet.add(current);
            if (current.equals(goal)) {
                return path(current);
            } else {
                neighbours(current, blocked);
            }
        }

        return Collections.emptyList();
    }

    /** Temporary solution **/
    public void refreshContext() {
        // do I really need to do that every search?
        this.matrix = new Vertex[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            this.matrix[i] = new Vertex[columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] =  new Vertex(i, j);
            }
        }

        openList.clear();
        closedSet.clear();
    }

    private void neighbours(Vertex current, boolean[][] blocked) {
        int row = current.getRow();
        int column = current.getColumn();

        int lower = row + 1;
        if (lower < rows && !blocked[lower][column]) {
            checkAdjacentVertex(current, lower, column);
        }

        int left = column - 1;
        if (left >= 0 && !blocked[row][left]) {
            checkAdjacentVertex(current, row, left);
        }

        int right = column + 1;
        if (right < columns && !blocked[row][right]) {
            checkAdjacentVertex(current, row, right);
        }

        int upper = row - 1;
        if (upper >= 0 && !blocked[upper][column]) {
            checkAdjacentVertex(current, upper, column);
        }
    }

    private void checkAdjacentVertex(Vertex current, int row, int column) {
        Vertex adjacent = matrix[row][column];
        if (!closedSet.contains(adjacent)) {
            int g = ComputationUtils.g(current, cost);
            if (!openList.contains(adjacent)) {
                updateVertex(adjacent, current, g, ComputationUtils.f(adjacent));
                openList.add(adjacent);
            } else {
                if (g < adjacent.getG()) {
                    updateVertex(adjacent, current, g, ComputationUtils.f(adjacent));

                    // as no update operation by default we need to remove and add node again
                    openList.remove(adjacent);
                    openList.add(adjacent);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // considering that I need only the last vertex I may need to adjust it
    private List<Vertex> path(Vertex reachedGoal) {
        List<Vertex> path = new ArrayList<>();
        path.add(reachedGoal);

        Vertex parent;
        while ((parent = reachedGoal.getParent()) != null) {
            path.add(0, parent);
            reachedGoal = parent;
        }
        return path;
    }

    private void updateVertex(Vertex v, Vertex parent, int g, int f) {
        v.setParent(parent);
        v.setG(g);
        v.setF(f); // order is important as F depends on G
    }

}
```

It supposed to work for multiple bots (threads) over the same table. To achieve that I created `concurrent context` class that looks like this

```
public class AStarShortestPathConcurrentContext implements IObservable<ChangeStateEvent> {
    private AStarShortestPathContext searchContext;
    private boolean[][] blocked;
    private List<IObserver<ChangeStateEvent>> observers;

    public AStarShortestPathConcurrentContext(int rows, int columns, int cost) {
        searchContext = new AStarShortestPathContext(rows, columns, cost);
        blocked = DataUtils.generateEmptyBoolMatrix(rows, columns);
        observers = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public synchronized Vertex next(Vertex startVertex, Vertex goalVertex, String identifier) {
        List<Vertex> path = searchContext.find(startVertex, goalVertex, blocked);
        // start vertex is 0, next vertex is 1
        Vertex next = path.get(1);
        updateBlockedTable(startVertex, next);

        // basically notify Swing JTable to update values in cells and force rendering
        notifyObserver(ChangeStateEvent
            .builder()
            .identifier(identifier)
            .newState(NPCWalkState
                .builder()
                .row(next.getRow())
                .column(next.getColumn())
                .build())
            .previousState(NPCWalkState
                .builder()
                .row(startVertex.getRow())
                .column(startVertex.getColumn())
                .build())
            .build());
        return next;
    }

    private void updateBlockedTable(Vertex startVertex, Vertex next) {
        int blocked_row = next.getRow();
        int blocked_column = next.getColumn();

        int released_row = startVertex.getRow();
        int released_column = startVertex.getColumn();

        blocked[blocked_row][blocked_column] = true;
        blocked[released_row][released_column] = false;
    }

    @Override
    public void addObserver(IObserver<ChangeStateEvent> observer) {
        observers.add(observer);
    }

    @Override
    public void notifyObserver(ChangeStateEvent data) {
        observers
            .parallelStream()
            .forEach(observer -> observer.receiveNotification(data));
    }
}
```

And that class is used in the threads.

```
public class WalkableNPCThread implements Runnable {
    private int speed;
    private String objectId;
    private AStarShortestPathConcurrentContext searchContext;
    private Vertex startVertex;
    private Vertex goalVertex;

    public WalkableNPCThread(WalkableNPC npc, AStarShortestPathConcurrentContext searchContext) {
        this.speed = npc.getSpeed();
        this.searchContext = searchContext;
        this.objectId = npc.getIdentifier();
    }

    public void configureWalk(int initialRow, int initialColumn, int goalRow, int goalColumn) {
        startVertex = new Vertex(initialRow, initialColumn);
        goalVertex = new Vertex(goalRow, goalColumn);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        while (!startVertex.equals(goalVertex)) {
            ThreadUtils.delaySeconds(speed);
            Vertex nextStep = searchContext.next(startVertex, goalVertex, objectId);
            startVertex = new Vertex(nextStep);
        }
    }
}
```

The table is the same for all threads, so I instantiate `AStarShortestPathConcurrentContext` only once and pass it as a constructor parameter to each thread. It seems to work fine.

What is bothering me is that method

```
public synchronized Vertex next(Vertex startVertex, Vertex goalVertex, String identifier) {
    List<Vertex> path = searchContext.find(startVertex, goalVertex, blocked);
    // start vertex is 0, next vertex is 1
    Vertex next = path.get(1);
    updateBlockedTable(startVertex, next);

    // basically notify Swing JTable to update values in cells and force rendering
    notifyObserver(ChangeStateEvent
        .builder()
        .identifier(identifier)
        .newState(NPCWalkState
            .builder()
            .row(next.getRow())
            .column(next.getColumn())
            .build())
        .previousState(NPCWalkState
            .builder()
            .row(startVertex.getRow())
            .column(startVertex.getColumn())
            .build())
        .build());
    return next;
}
```

I syncronize it in order to prevent updates of `blocked` field by other threads and also to prevent the update the `AStarShortestPathContext` when doing the search (I refresh it for each thread before the search).

I am not sure if I really need to block the whole method `next`. Is there a way to achieve the same better?

I was thinking for using `lock` for the whole method instead of `synchronized` but still it would block the whole method.

**Edit**
Utility classes look like this

```
@UtilityClass
public class ComputationUtils {

    // heuristics in our case - manhattan distance
    public int h(Vertex s, Vertex s_goal) {
        return Math.abs(s.getColumn() - s_goal.getColumn()) + Math.abs(s.getRow() - s_goal.getRow());
    }

    // incremental cost of moving from node s to next node with cost
    public int g(Vertex s, int cost) {
        return s.getG() + cost;
    }

    // total cost of the path via node s
    public int f(Vertex s) {
        return s.getG() + s.getH();
    }

    // approx. distance from each cell to goal
    public void updateEuristic(Vertex[][] matrix, Vertex goal) {
        for (Vertex[] row : matrix) {
            for (Vertex cell : row) {
                int h = ComputationUtils.h(cell, goal);
                cell.setH(h);
            }
        }
    }
}

@UtilityClass
public class ThreadUtils {

    public void delaySeconds(int seconds) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000 / seconds);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

@UtilityClass
public class DataUtils {

    public List<String>[][] generateEmptyListMatrx(int rows, int columns) {
        List<String>[][] lines = new List[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i] = new List[columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                lines[i][j] = new ArrayList<>();
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public String[][] generateEmptyStringMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
        String[][] lines = new String[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
            lines[i] = new String[columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                lines[i][j] = "";
            }
        }
        return lines;
    }

    public boolean[][] generateEmptyBoolMatrix(int rows, int columns) {
        boolean[][] matrix = new boolean[rows][];
        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
            matrix[i] = new boolean[columns];
            for (int j = 0; j < columns; j++) {
                matrix[i][j] = false;
            }
        }
        return matrix;
    }

}
```

Comment: @dfhwze yeah, they are all mine.

Comment: Because the source code is not included. Do you think reviewers should know the content of these classes or are they not critical/relevant for your question?

Comment: @dfhwze I added source code, but I don't think they are critical

Comment: So you want multiple threads trying to figure out the same path, or multiple threads each figuring out a different path?

Comment: multiple threads trying to figure out paths to their goals (paths might intercept, but two cannot enter the same cell at the same time)

Comment: Ok, so the issue is that the NPCs are moving as the threads run, not on game clock ticks, and you don't want them to bump into each other? I'm not a game programmer, but I'd expect everyone moving on ticks on an internal game clock, not arbitrarily as their threads get CPU. Don't you want NPC speed determined by you, not by which threads are the CPU's favorites? I would expect pathing to get computed once, everybody to move on game clock ticks, and if your next step is occupied, wait a few ticks and then A* again.

Comment: @EricStein Your last comment should be promoted to an answer, wouldn't you say?

Comment: @dfhwze Coulda been, but I didn't have time to do one up properly, and now it's been so long that the review probably doesn't add value.

Comment: @EricStein This question has one answer, and without votes. Your answer might be worth something.

Answer (score 1):

## Method Names

Robert C. Martin, who wrote the book "Clean Code", sad

> [Don’t Use a Comment When You Can Use a Function or a Variable](https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/45372.Robert_C_Martin?page=2)

In your case you have the function (or method) but you need to clarify what it does with a comment because of the meaningless name of the method.

> ```
> // heuristics in our case - manhattan distance
> public int h(Vertex s, Vertex s_goal) { /* ... */ }
>
> // incremental cost of moving from node s to next node with cost
> public int g(Vertex s, int cost) { /* ... */ }
>
> // total cost of the path via node s
> public int f(Vertex s) { /* ... */ }
> ```

They could be named like `distance`, `incrementalCost` and `totalCost`.

Simply change the name of the

## [Feature Envy](http://wiki.c2.com/?FeatureEnvySmell)

> The whole point of objects is that they are a technique to package data with the processes used on that data. [...]

Why do you decide to use a `ComputationUtils` instead of object methods on `Vertex`?

Two examples:

> ```
> public int h(Vertex s, Vertex s_goal) {
>     return Math.abs(s.getColumn() - s_goal.getColumn()) + Math.abs(s.getRow() - s_goal.getRow());
>    }
> ```

```
public int distanceTo(Vertex other) {
    return Math.abs(column - other.column) + Math.abs(row - other.row);
}
```

and

> ```
> public int f(Vertex s) {
>    return s.getG() + s.getH();
> }
> ```

```
public int totalCost() {
    return g + h;
}
```

---

## Hidden Methods

This point goes hand in hand with *Feature Envy*. You have a heavy use of the getter methods of `Vertex` and let other objects interact with the data.

> ```
> int g = ComputationUtils.g(current, cost);
> /* ... */
> if (g < adjacent.getG()) {/* ... */}
> ```

The same could be expressed with a method `current#hasSmallerCostAs(otherVertex)`. This would improve the readability by reducing the number of variables (`g`), additional operations (`ComputationUtils#g`) and abstracts the logic trough the name of the method.

```
if(current.hasSmallerCostAs(adjacent)) {/* ... */}
```

Comment: I think it is due to it being partially based on paper and article where each function mentioned separately and names as `f(g)` etc.. Regarding methods...well usually I separate logic from the domain model.